# I am hoping to find any information available regarding this stamp (Characters identified: 福 日本館印)

Tags: translation, character-identification, seal

[image]

[image]
[image]

This stamp is on an Enso circle that I purchased at auction.  I'm hoping to find out any information that may be gleaned from it.

Comment: Thank you for the edit.

Comment: I think you'd get a better answer at Japanese Language Stack Exchange.

Comment: Thank you so much.  Sorry for the naivete.

Comment: This seems to be the "Japanese style Chinese" (especially the character `本` ), which is used in Japan. you can ask this question from japanese.

and the interesting thing is: `印` is rorated 90 degree comparing `日本馆`

Comment: Is it in a book?